# How to add validation for this case in rails 2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-2

I have text field with  name print run  which has to be validated in the format of

Valid values for the print run field, are positive integers, 'Unlimited', and 'Silent'.

I have added  validation like this

```
VALID_NAMES = %w(Unlimited silent  #k)
  validates_inclusion_of :print_run, :in => VALID_NAMES
```

how to proceed for validation to  accept positive integers also...

```
validates_numericality_of :print_run, :only_integer => true, :message => "can only be whole number."
```

the above validation accept only numeric

```
Integer(attributes_before_type_cast["print_run"])        
errors.add_to_base( "print_run must be a number")
```

the above statement accepts only the number but no validation for positive integers

how  to proceed with this..

Answer (score 0):

if you want only positive integers,

```
validates_numericality_of :print_run, :only_integer => true,:greater_than_or_equal_to => 0, :message => "can only be whole number."
```

if you want **Unlimited** or **silent** or **positive integers**

```
validates_format_of :print_run, :with => /\A(Unlimited|silent|\d*)\z/, :message => "your custom message"
```